# FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER FMOD error! (23) File not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, effects, fmod

I am using `FMOD` to add effect on audio files.

here is my code

```
    char cDest[200] = {0}; 
    NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordName.wav", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"%@",fileName);

    [fileName getCString:cDest maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
    result = system->setOutput(FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER); ERRCHECK(result);


    result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL | FMOD_INIT_ENABLE_PROFILE, NULL);
    ERRCHECK(result);
```

I am getting this error `FMOD error! (23) File not found.`  when add `FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER`

Please help me

Comment: Did you find the solution for this??
I am also facing this problem.

Comment: I have posted my solution below. if still having issue let me know. hope I amy help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friends I fixed this issue, myself

Here is the code. hope it will help some one

```
[strSavedFile getCString:cDest maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
result = system->setOutput(FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER_NRT); ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, cDest);
```

Just change

```
result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL | FMOD_INIT_ENABLE_PROFILE, NULL);
```

with

```
result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, cDest);
```

And enjoy

Comment: i want to add high pass filer (or any other filter) to the audio file and then save it to the document directory.
Below is my code.Its not giving me the result. can you please suggest, where i am wrong...

Answer (score 2):

i want to add high pass filer (or any other filter) to the audio file and then save it to the document directory.
Below is my code.Its not giving me the result. can you please suggest where i am wrong...

```
FMOD_RESULT   result        = FMOD_OK;
char          buffer[200]   = {0};
unsigned int  version       = 0;

result = FMOD::System_Create(&system); 
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->getVersion(&version);
ERRCHECK(result);

if (version < FMOD_VERSION)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "You are using an old version of FMOD %08x.  This program requires %08x\n", version, FMOD_VERSION);
    exit(-1);
}

[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/song1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] getCString:buffer maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

char cDest[200] = {0}; 
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordName.wav", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];

[fileName getCString:cDest maxLength:200 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
result = system->setOutput(FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER); 
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL | FMOD_INIT_ENABLE_PROFILE, cDest);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->createSound(buffer, FMOD_SOFTWARE, NULL, &sound);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound, false, &channel);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->createDSPByType(FMOD_DSP_TYPE_HIGHPASS, &dsphighpass);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = system->addDSP(dsphighpass, NULL);
ERRCHECK(result);
```